# Java multiple threads database access

Tags: java, database, multithreading, synchronization

What could be the best solution for multithreaded Java application to ensure that all threads access db synchronously? For example, each thread represents separate transaction, and first checks db for value and then depending on answer has to insert or update some fields in database (note between check, insert and commit application is doing other processing). But the problem is that another thread might be doing just the same thing on same table.

More specific example. Thread T1 starts transaction, then checks table ENTITY_TABLE for entry with code '111'. If found updates its date, if not found inserts new entry, then commits transaction. Now imagine thread T2 does exactly same thing. Now there are few problems:

1. T1 and T2 checks db and find nothing and both insert same entry.
2. T1 checks db, find entry with old date, but on commit T2 already has updated entry to more recent date.
3. If we use cache and synchronize access to cache we have a problem: T1 acquires lock checks db and cache if not found add to cache, release lock, commit. T2 does the same, finds entry in cache going to commit. But T1 transaction fails and is roll backed. Now T2 is in bad shape, because it should insert to ENTITY_TABLE but doesn't know that.
4. more?

I'm working on creating simple custom cache with syncronization and solving problem 3. But maybe there is some more simple solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be dealt with primarily within the DB, by configuring the desired [*transaction isolation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) level. Then on top of this, you need to select your locking strategy ([optimistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) or pessimistic).

Without transaction isolation, you will have a hard time trying to ensure transaction integrity solely in the Java domain. Especially taking into consideration that even if the DB is currently accessed only from your Java app, this may change in the future.

Now as to which isolation level to choose, from your description it might seem that you need the highest isolation level, *serializable*. However, in practice this tends
 to be a real performance hog due to extensive locking. So you may want to reevaluate your requirements to find the best balance of isolation and performance for your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. The thing is application must be very performant, it might run on 16 or maybe even 32 threads. And each starts transaction, do a lot of processing, then takes results and do inserts and updates on commit step - all in jdbc batches(for performance). Then transaction is commited. Anyway in my situation serializable level would be too much especially for 32 threads. I hope i will be able to solve this with cache in Java application.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to SQL SELECT a row from a database, and then later UPDATE the same row, you have 2 choices as a Java developer.

1. SELECT with ROWLOCK, or whatever the
   row lock syntax is for your
   particular data base.
2. SELECT the row, do your processing,
   and just before you're ready to
   update, SELECT the row again with ROWLOCK to see
   if any other thread made changes. 
   If the two SELECTS return the same
   values, UPDATE.  If not, throw an
   error or do your processing again.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something about 2, because it sounds wrong to me. In my interpretation, this approach does not AT ALL protect from race conditions. Just because you didn't encounter a change between your two reads doesn't mean that there will not be a change just before you now do your write.

Comment: @Dreamspace President:  You're partially correct.  What you're doing in option 2 is minimizing the probability that a change will occur before you do your write.  I should have mentioned in the answer that the second select locks the row.

Comment: Oh. That's how you meant it. Then I know what workflow you had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is **[transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)**.

Seems like you need to have each thread lock the row concerned in the where clause, which requires serializable isolation.

Answer (score 2):

I tumbled into this problem when working with a multi-threaded Java program that was using a Sqllite database. It uses file locking so I had to make sure that only one thread was doing work at the same time.

I basically ended up with using synchronized. When the ConnectionFactory returns a db connection, it also returns a lock object that one should lock when using the connection. So you could do synchronization lock manually, or create a subclass of the class below which does it for you:

```
 /**
  * Subclass this class and implement the persistInTransaction method to perform
  * an update to the database.
  */
 public abstract class DBOperationInTransaction {

     protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBOperationInTransaction.class.getName());

     public DBOperationInTransaction(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
         DBConnection con = null;

         try {
             con = connectionFactory.getConnection();

             if(con == null) {
                 logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not get db connection");
                 throw new RuntimException("Could not get db connection");
             }

             synchronized (con.activityLock) {
                 con.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                 persistInTransaction(con.connection);
                 con.connection.commit();
             }

         } catch (Exception e) {
             logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to persist data:", e);
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         } finally {
             if(con != null) {
                 //Close con.connection silently.
             }
         }
     }

     /**
      * Method for persisting data within a transaction. If any SQLExceptions
      * occur they are logged and the transaction is rolled back.
      * 
      * In the scope of the method there is a logger object available that any
      * errors/warnings besides sqlException that you want to log.
      * 
      * @param con
      *            Connection ready for use, do not do any transaction handling
      *            on this object.
      * @throws SQLException
      *             Any SQL exception that your code might throw. These errors
      *             are logged. Any exception will rollback the transaction.
      * 
      */
     abstract protected void persistInTransaction(Connection con) throws SQLException;

 }
```

And the DBConnection struct:

```
 final public class DBConnection {
     public final Connection connection;
     public final String activityLock;

     public DBConnection(Connection connection, String activityLock) {
         this.connection = connection;
         this.activityLock = activityLock;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I think you would have to lock the table before you query it. This will force sequential operation of your threads. Your threads should then be prepared for the fact that they will have to wait for the lock and of course, the lock acquisition might time out. This could introduce quite a bottleneck into your application as well as your threads will all have to queue up for database resources.